# Is TCP header the same as TCP segment?

Tags: networking, tcp, headers, packet

So, is a TCP header actually the same thing as a TCP segment? I was reading [this](http://www.firewall.cx/networking-topics/protocols/tcp/131-protocols-tcp-segment.html) page, 
where it reads near the end that:

> Even though it might seem they are, in most cases, when referring to
>   the TCP header, we are talking about the header without the data,
>   whereas a TCP segment includes the data.

And then just below this it reads:

> be sure to keep in mind that the 'TCP Header' is the same thing as a
>   'TCP Segment', meaning it's the TCP header information plus the Data

These statements are contradictory. What is the truth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second paragraph is incorrect. Maybe the intention was to say packet rather than header. This wording would make more sense:

> be sure to keep in mind that the 'TCP packet' is the same thing as a 'TCP Segment', meaning it's the TCP header information plus the Data

Comment: You just got in there first and clarified this for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with the answers provided by kce and kasperd regarding the meaning of and difference between the TCP Header and a TCP Segment, I'll add that AFAIK the correct term for the "package" at the TCP layer is `TCP Segment`. Here are what I believe to be the correct terms for a data `package` at each layer of the OSI model:

Layers 7 through 5 (Application, Presentation, Session) = PDU (Protocol Data Unit)

Layer 4 (TCP, UDP) = TCP Segment or UDP Datagram

Layer 3 (IP) = Packet

Layer 2 (Data Link Layer) = Frame (Ethernet Frame)

At Layer 1 the data is put `on the wire` as bits/electronic signals

Comment: where would you fit the 'datagram' into this picture?

Comment: See my edit....

Comment: RFC791 (IPv4) uses "datagram" for the unit at the IP layer. IPv6 specs use "packet". Apparently the word "datagram" is out of style.

Answer (score 1):

The truth is that people don't use vocabulary consistently and I would agree with your assessment that the sentence is contradictory (or a mistake).

Arguably the closest thing to a standard is the RFCs. In this case [RFC793](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt) where a segment and header are defined thusly:

> **datagram**
>
> ```
>       A message sent in a packet switched computer communications
>       network.
> ```
>
> **header**
>
> ```
>       Control information at the beginning of a message, segment,
>       fragment, packet or block of data.
> ```
>
> **module**
>
> ```
>       An implementation, usually in software, of a protocol or other
>       procedure.
> ```
>
> **segment**
>
> ```
>       A logical unit of data, in particular a TCP segment is the
>       unit of data transferred between a pair of TCP modules.
> ```

I would say your assessment is correct in this case (although I'd be happy to be shown otherwise), however the language is a little wishy-washy because you could interpret "unit of data...transferred between TCP modules" as to include the entire datagram.